# How to "nicely" map the keys of a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, idioms

I have an array of key-values incoming from one system and want to send the same values with different keys to another. That is, we have

```
$map = [
  'sys_a_1' => 'sys_b_1',
  'sys_a_2' => 'sys_b_2',
];

$data = [
  'sys_a_1' => 'data_1',
  'sys_a_2' => 'data_2',
];
```

and we want

```
$result = [
  'sys_b_1' => 'data_1',
  'sys_b_2' => 'data_2',
];
```

and I can do it with a loop:

```
foreach ($map as $from => $to) {
  if (!empty($data[$from])) {
    $result[$to] = $data[$from];
  }
}
```

but it just chafes at me there's no `array_something()` way of doing it. `array_combine($map, array_intersect_key($data, $map))` *almost* does it but `array_intersect_key` doesn't reorder so it'll be all out of whack.

Comment: I recommend sticking with your foreach loop.

Comment: Unless your `$data` values are guaranteed not to be an empty string or 0 or false or null, I would use `isset` rather than `!empty`

Answer (score 0):

What about with `array_combine()`,

```
<?php
$map = [
  'sys_a_1' => 'sys_b_1',
  'sys_a_2' => 'sys_b_2',
];

$data = [
  'sys_a_1' => 'data_1',
  'sys_a_2' => 'data_2',
];

$result = array_combine($map,$data);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/C2HDV

Comment: This will only work if the keys in each array are in the same order: https://3v4l.org/2Jgsg